# Filtering results on custom fields using $query_vars

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to extend the search in my wordpress theme by filtering firstly on post_type (CPT using PODS) and then by fields within the post_type.

I have the following code:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'custom_filter_search_result_by_post_type' );

function custom_filter_search_result_by_post_type( $query_vars ) {

if ( empty( $query_vars['s'] ) || empty( $_GET['post_type'] ) ) {
    return $query_vars;
}

$post_type        = $_GET['post_type'];
$search_value     = $_GET['s'];
$valid_post_types = get_post_types( array(
    'public'             => TRUE,
    'publicly_queryable' => TRUE
) );


if ( ! isset( $valid_post_types[ $post_type ] ) ) {
    return $query_vars;
}

$query_vars['post_type'] = $post_type;

echo '<script>console.log("Searching in ' . $post_type . ' for ' . $search_value . '")</script>';

switch( $post_type ) {
        case 'book':
        $query_vars->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'book_author',
                    'value' => $search_value,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ));
    break;      
    case 'jobs':
    break;
    default:
break;
}

echo '<script>console.log(' . json_encode($query_vars) . ')</script>';
return $query_vars;
}
```

However the array inside the switch is causing a blank screen so there is clearly an error in there somewhere, but I'm familiar enough with the syntax to find it.

Essentially, I have a single search term and I'd like the match that to either the title or book author or publisher. is this possible within the filter code above?

**** EDIT ****

I've updated the code to read:

```
$meta_query = array(
             'relation'      => 'OR',
                array(
                  'key'       => 'book_author',
                  'value'     => $_GET['author'],
                  'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                )
              );

 $query_vars->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

And I do now get results, however I have had to pass 's' as empty and add author to the querystring (not desired). This has resulted in all books being displayed and not filtered at all.

I believe this is probably because the main bulk of the search is conducted within the theme itself so when simply using 's' parameter as the criteria it already has zero results to filter. - Doesn't explain why when 's' is blank but author is filled out, it still doesn't filter the results.